# displays the position of the form location dynamically C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display the position of form 2 according to my wishes in Form1, to be precise, placed on the right. 
 I write this code in form1 :

```
     public static int ParentX, ParentY;

     private void BT_ShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          using (Form2 Frm = new Form2 ())
          {
              ParentX = Location.X;
              ParentY = Location.Y;
              Frm.ShowDialog();
          }
```

and this code is in form2 :

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Location = new Point(Form1.ParentX + 385, Form1.ParentY + 120);
    }
```

when form1 is in the normal position, the code works as I want, but when form1 is in Maximize position, Form2 is no longer in the position I want. 
I want form2 to appear in the same position when form1 is in Normal and Maximal positions. how to achieve that?

sorry if this question is wrong, I'm still in the learning stage, and not very good at English.

Comment: @Dai oh, sorry, I edited it..

Comment: The Location property: _Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control relative to the upper-left corner of its container._

Comment: When calling ShowDialog add your form as parameter like `Frm.ShowDialog(this)`. That will make that form the owner of the other form. In Form load you can now ask for the location of the Owner like Owner.Location and set you actual forms location from there.

Answer (score 0):

Does this Work?

```
if (Form1.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
//Place form
} else {
Location = new Point(Form1.ParentX + 385, Form1.ParentY + 120);
}
```

Comment: i've written code like that, but it's not working..

Comment: Since you are getting the Location property of Form1, when Form1 is maximized these values are 0,0 resulting in Form 2 being placed at 385,120. Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: I seem to have missed something missing, just added a command line bit like so:
if (Form1.ActiveForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
and now working fine. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ActiveForm is risky. You are in the context of changing activity between forms. So be sure to where you put your code. ActiveForm can already be your Form2 if called late in activity change. Better to not really on that. See direct comment that you might rather want to use the Owner concept between forms then relying on static variables and ActiveForm.

Comment: @Ralf yes, what you said is correct.. adding ActiveForm is not the right step, your suggestion give me useful input. Thank you very much.